# Why did this header style stop working?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

Until a few weeks ago, the style worked perfectly and this was the result:

[image]

But recently it has stopped working without any modification and I have no idea why, now it produces:
[image]

How can I recover that style? Or how can I make one equal.

the code is

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color,lmodern,titlesec}
 \newcommand\chptitle[1]{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-87pt}{\raggedright#1}}
 \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{12pt}}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{{
    \fontsize{4.1em}{4.1em}\selectfont\color{black}%
     \thechapter}\hsp\textcolor{blue}{\vrule height 2.7em width 1pt}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\chptitle}

 \begin{document}

  \chapter{Aaaa bbbb}

   aa

   \chapter{Aaaa bbbb Aaaa bbbb Aaaa bbbb}

   bb

   \end{document}
```

The list of files generated by `\listfiles` in the log file is

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   color.sty    2016/01/03 v1.1b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
titlesec.sty    2016/03/15 v2.10.1 Sectioning titles
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: On a recent TeXLive 2016 installation there is no problem: I see numbers and blue lines in front of the headers. So check your installation.

Comment: @gernot I have installed texlive-full last night from the ubuntu repositories, but a friend with miktek on windows has reported the same problem.

Comment: Any errors in the log file? Add `\listfiles` as first line, then you will get a list of files with version information in the log file.

Comment: @gernot Nope, the log file does not contain errors, although I have added the list of files as you recommended.

Comment: You've been bitten by the bug in version 2.10.1 of `titlesec`. Update to version 2.10.2. Unfortunately TeX Live/Debian always lags behind.